# Communities, Events, and Without Sharing

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, partner-communities

I'm having an odd problem (I think it's odd, at least).

I have a lightning component which calls a controller method to retrieve a list of events.

The events may not belong to the current user (Events are not ACTUALLY events in the traditional sense - they represent something else. Bad modelling by a previous consultancy), but I want to select all events which are related to a particular campaign ID

I've added Without Sharing to the controller.

I've added the lightning component to Salesforce1 via a Lightning component tab, and this works fine. All events are returned without any issues.

The customer also wants partner community users to be able to access the lightning app via Salesforce1. It appears that this cannot be done via a Lightning Component tab, so I've added the component to a lightning page in app builder and added it to the community that way.

Everything works fine like this, except that when using the page as a community user, you cannot see anyone else's events.

I thought that adding Without Sharing to the controller would get around this, but I'm guessing it works differently for partner community users?

Is there a way to bypass this security in apex for community users?

Apex:

```
public without sharing class EventSelector
{
    @auraEnabled
    public static List<Event> SelectSessionsForCourse(Id courseCampaignId)
    {
        return [SELECT Id, Subject, StartDateTime, WhatId
                FROM Event
                WHERE WhatId = :courseCampaignId
                AND IsRecurrence = false
                ORDER BY StartDateTime Asc];
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind exposing some apex here ?want to see if there is any filters in query apart from without sharing keyword

Comment: Sure - apex added. It's not exactly rocket science. When I run this within SF1 as a non-community user, it brings back the data correctly.

Comment: Another minor breakthrough, there is a field called "Public" on the event which makes the event visible to community users if checked. I've updated this on one event and can now see it in my app. Still not ideal, because that means we'll have to data load loads of records and put a workflow in place to make sure the field is always true in future. Would prefer to find out if there's a way to just expose all events by default!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue or get a workaround?